# Query a database table using a foreign key ( where) using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i m new to hibernate, so the question might look stupid.

I have the two tables:

***Application:***

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Application extends BaseSimpleEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String appID;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Searcheable
    private LocalizedString name;
...
```

***Compilation:***

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Compilation extends BaseSimpleEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String uid;
    @ManyToOne
    private Application application;
    @Column
    private DateTime creationDate;
    @Column
    private DateTime finishDate;
    @Column
    private String path;
....
```

and i want to get a list of Compilation that matches a given Application.

i did the following query:

```
@Query("FROM Compilation c WHERE c.Application.id = :applicationId")
List<Compilation> findValidCompialiton(@Param("applicationId") Long applicationId);
```

But it is not working.

***Error:***

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   Application of: xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.Compilation [FROM
>   xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.Compilation c WHERE c.Application.id = :applicationId]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be :

```
@Query("FROM Compilation c WHERE c.application.appID = :applicationId")
```

You have created an alias `c` for entity, Hibernate tries to check the `Compilation`, now you can access the properties of the `Compilation` entity. Now the property in `Compilation` class is `application` and this `application` property represents the `Application` which has the field `appID`